# storing values with multiple lines with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to help out a friend by writing a program that continuously reads temperatures updates from his cooling machines

The code should go through cooling machine data to register the temperatures.
Periodically the following data will be printed:
Highest temperature per machine, lowest temperature, highest temperature 
and top 5 temperatures overall.

Below tempinput will be received every 5 minutes in the format below. 
For explanation purposes I have added a second line of tempinput to this code (received 5 minutes later).

```
tempinput = [
{
"Machine":"Cool-01",
"Date":"01/01/2018",
"Time":"12:25:00", 
"CurrTemp":"23.52"},
{"Machine":"Cool-02",
"Date":"01/01/2018",
"Time":"12:25:00", 
"CurrTemp":"22.02"}
]
#tempinput = [
#{
#"Machine":"Cool-01",
#"Date":"01/01/2018",
#"Time":"12:30:00", 
#"CurrTemp":"23.50"},
#{"Machine":"Cool-02",
#"Date":"01/01/2018",
#"Time":"12:30:00", 
#"CurrTemp":"22.12"}
#]
```

The key = Machine.
I then want to store the values per Machine in such a way that it will keep the values of the last 2 hours per Machine in memory (= 24 readings).
After the first 24 readings and assignments I want the system to 'remove' the oldest stored value (based on an index not on time as this is sometimes ‘off’) and then place the other 23 lines a place down the ladder and fill the removed value with the latest values...

I am really struggling how I can store the data as described above. After 'for key in dict_in_list', I am lost (do not know how to proceed). I cant get my head around the storing of 24 lines of data per machine. I hope someone can point me in the right direction and that my question is not downgraded (i have searched through the entire Stackoverflow site and could not find any example that I understood / reflects my request). Thanks in advance.

```
  for dict_in_list in tempinput:
      for key in dict_in_list:
        .....here i am stuck; tried a lot of ways but nothing works
```

Comment: You can discard the oldest element in the list with:

    my_list = my_list[1:]

Comment: You might be able to use [`collections.deque(maxlen=24)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Answer (score 0):

"Machine" is not the only key. "Date" and "Time" etc. are also keys.
I suggest you initiate a list of 24 dicts (one dict being one entire reading) and loop over those, fill them in until the last one and then start at the beginning again.
So you will only need the first for-loop.